# PowerApps changes not reflected in Power BI report until manual refresh

Tags: powerbi, powerapps

I'm using PowerApps for a Power BI visual in my Power BI report.

I'm facing an issue where after making changes in PowerApps and publishing them, the latest changes are not immediately reflected in the report (even the PowerApps seems to reload with the Splash Screen).

To see the latest changes, I have to manually refresh the visual: either by toggling between the report's page or reloading the Power BI Service.

Is there a way to ensure that the latest changes are automatically reflected without the need for manual intervention?